# Custom button not visible in Salesforce for Ipad tablets (only visible for desktop and android)

Tags: custom-button, tab, ipad, lightning-home-page

I have a custom button on record page. When I am on the page from the desktop or Mobile, it shows up and its completely perfect working. But I am trying to to access the page from ipad, then the button is not visible

Comment: Mostly quick actions added to the layouts are visible from apps and not all the custom buttons

Comment: how can i fix this ?

Comment: What is the button type that is missing?

Comment: Button Type is Visualforce Area